# Find Last Column -- returns wrong column

Tags: excel, vba

In rowTop (i.e. Row 1), I have blank cells between Column 1 and Column 516. Then I have cells with values between Column 517 and Column 573. Then blanks all the way till the end of the spreadsheet.

The line below consistently returns Column 517. It really feels like VBA is pressing Ctrl+Left twice in a row.

```
With ActiveSheet    
   colLast = Cells(rowTop,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 
End With
```

I've used the same code for months (including this morning) and have always run successfully until now. Is there a way to fix? It feels like a glitchy/buggy VBA rather than wrong code.

Comment: What is the value of `ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Column + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count -1`?

Comment: Have you checked rowTop=1? Have you tried doing this manually?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Column returns 517. ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count -1 returns 516. I am confused. I am staring at my worksheet and the columns definitely have value up to Columns 573...

Comment: @SJR rowTop is definitely 1. I checked.

Comment: And it's definitely the right sheet in the right workbook?

Comment: @SJR Yes..Sounds like a dead-end. I will re-write the entire code and hopefully it somehow fixes itself

Comment: Try deleting the columns from 574 to the last column and check if your issue is resolved. If not then after the above step run this code and tell what does it returns 

Cells(rowTop,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).End(xlToRight).Column

Comment: You have `With ActiveSheet` but don't reference it in the next line (there is no dot `.` before `Cells` nor `Columns`). I don't think it matters here since the default without qualifier should be `ActiveSheet` anyways.